# How do I simplify $\overline{(\bar{X} + Z\bar{Y} + Y\bar{Z})(\bar{X}+Y\bar{Z})}$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

$\overline{(\bar{X} + Z\bar{Y} + Y\bar{Z})(\bar{X}+Y\bar{Z})}$

The farthest I've gotten is DeMorgans:

$X(\bar{Z} + Y)(\bar{Y} + Z) + X(\bar{Y} + Z)$

The answer should be $X\bar{Y} + XZ$, but I'm unable to get anywhere close to it. I tried foiling the binomial but it results in a single `X` value when the whole expression is evaluated, and that's not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from where you stopped using $1$ for $True$

\begin{eqnarray*} X(\bar{Z} + Y)(\bar{Y} + Z) + X(\bar{Y} + Z)
& = & X(\bar{Y} + Z)((\bar{Z} + Y) + 1) \\
& \stackrel{x+1=1}{=} & X(\bar{Y} + Z)\\
& = & X\bar{Y} + XZ
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Can I get an explanation of the first step? Is X factored out? And where does the one come from?

Comment: @S.Coughing When you do Boolean algebra, you need some basic rules like $1b=b, b+1=1$ and distributivity $a(b+c)=ab+ac$. In the first step I use distributivity and $1b=b$ together. You will see such "tricks" quite often when transforming Boolean expressions. So, it's good to get accustomed to such rules.